# Fragment counterpart of getSupportFragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

Is there a counterpart of getSupportFragmentManager for fragments? Or is it just for FragmentActivity?

I have this

```
adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this, this.getSupportFragmentManager());
```

that goes to here

```
public MyPagerAdapter(TopFrag context, FragmentManager fm) {}
```

Comment: then what? Do you have any issue?

Comment: The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined, because it is for fragmentactivity. right?

Comment: Fragment has the method getFragmentManager which returns a FragmentManager.

Comment: @EarlOfEgo post your comment as an answer

Comment: But I'm going to pass it to the method findFragmentByTag, so I need it from the support.v4 library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was just to put the page adapter within the main activity. All good now. Thank you sirs. :)

Answer (score 0):

Fragment has the method `getFragmentManager()` which returns a FragmentManager.
so do:

```
adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this, this.getFragmentManager());
```

Comment: But I'm going to pass it to the method findFragmentByTag, so I need it from the support.v4 library.

Comment: I don't get your get your problem, sorry. Either you use fragments of the support library or you use the native fragments, introduced in API 11.

Answer (score 0):

Call this line of code inside your fragment.

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Since `getSupportFragmentManager()` is a public method, you can call it outside the activity too.